# How to pass URLs as a variable to an ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I created a playbook which clears cache, I'm trying to pass a url to a variable, and when I execute the playbook I get an empty array for that parameter.

In my playbook I have a `vars` module with this variable (`environment`), it gets defined when you pass in a variable to the ansible-playbook command

```yaml
vars:
    environment: "{{testenv}}"
```

```sh
-e testenv=https://www.test1.com
```

When I execute the playbook I get this error.
Do I need to format the url in someway?

> ```
> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "unknown url type: '[]/content/clear_cache?
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is coming from the fact that `environment` is a reserved variable, as pointed in the second row of this table in the documentation:

> | Valid variable names | Not valid |
> | --- | --- |
> | `foo` | `*foo`, [Python keywords](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) such as `async` and `lambda` |
> | `foo_env` | [playbook keywords](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#playbook-keywords) such as `environment` |
> | `foo_port` | `foo-port`, `foo port`, `foo.port` |
> | `foo5`, `_foo` | `5foo`, `12` |

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names*</sup>

So, you just need to change your variable name to something else and it will work.

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ _environment }}"
      vars:
        _environment: "{{ testenv }}"
```

When run:

```
$ ansible-playbook play.yml -e testenv=https://www.test1.com

PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "https://www.test1.com"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thank you so much, youre right!. I appreciate the help